# Accessing HTML via AIR's HTML Component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flex4

I can't seem to find anything in Adobe's documentation about accessing the HTML of a web page through the HTML component in AIR.

I've looked into "domWindow", but that seems to only return Javascript.

Is there a property I can access that has the whole of the HTML in string format or do I need to use URLLoader or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

[htmlText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5#htmlText)  ?

Comment: I was getting a "null" response when accessing that object. Although I didn't print out the whole object, so let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: Yeah, it's just null, unfortunately.

Comment: Bummer; that was a bit of a shock in the dark.  You can definitely use htmlText to populate it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having no luck finding this either.